# Ubuntu Cloud Image 20.04, cloud-init error

Tags: cloud-init

esxi 8.0, Ubuntu 20.04(focal). I've created cidata.ico with
hdiutil makehybrid -o cidata.iso cidata -iso -joliet

user-data content:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: demo
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACA...
```

getting

```
[    5.671765] cloud-init[680]: 2022-11-02 01:06:00,248 - schema.py[WARNING]: Invalid cloud-config provided: Please run 'sudo cloud-init schema --system' to see the schema errors.
```

Any way so I can see more details about this error?
thanks!

Comment: Did you follow the instructions provided in the error message?

Comment: After running the command as the error tells you then post the info in the question using edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root@me:~# cloud-init schema --system
Cloud config schema deprecations: 
Error:
Cloud config schema errors: users.0: {'groups': 'sudo', 'name': 'demo', 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'ssh-authorized-keys': ['ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EA'], 'sudo': 'ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

If you look at [the cloud-init docs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#users-and-groups), you'll see that `ssh-authorized-keys` is not a valid key. It has been deprecated and replaced with `ssh_authorized_keys`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That helped!

Comment: Im trying to ssh to the host:
ssh demo@192.168.50.159

getting: demo@192.168.50.159: Permission denied (publickey).

Any ideas why? 
thanks and appreciate it.